# Stability with 2 dimensional recursion functions.

Tags: recursion

First of all, hello.

I'm having trouble determining whether fixed points are stable or unstable.

I have a recursion function: 
\begin{align*}
f_{\alpha,\gamma}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
t\\
v
\end{array}\right)=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
(t+v)mod(2\pi)\\
\alpha v-\gamma cos(t+v))
\end{array}\right)
\end{align*}
and the fixed points: 
$(t^*,v^*)=(\arccos\left(\frac{2k\pi(\alpha-1)}{\gamma}\right),2k\pi)$

Can anyone tell me how to determine if a fixed point is stable or unstable?

Comment: It has to do with the Jacobian matrix and its eigenvalues. You can look it up, actually.